# Event "Paste" on TextArea Extjs 4.1

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, listener

I am trying to use paste event, to get the amount of text being copied and send a message (On the controller), right now i am sending an event to the "scope" which i am listener for...

```
                        xtype: 'textarea',
                        name: 'obs2',
                        margin: '0 0 10 110',
                        enforceMaxLength: true,
                        maxLength: 80,
                        columnWidth: 1,
                        rows: 3,
                        paste: {
                            element: 'inputEl',
                            fn: function (event, inputEl) {
                                var text = event.browserEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                                if (text.length > /*MaxLength*/ 80) {
                                    scope.fireEvent('exceedpaste', scope, /*MaxLength*/ 80, text.length);
                                }
                                return;
                             }
                        }
```

Problem is that, for a field that code works, for a textArea it doesn't works, maybe textArea doesn't have a html listener for paste or anything...

Anyone knows how to "listen" to paste on Textarea??

(1º Edit - This is trying to be achieved on chrome only, most recent version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ops, i forgot this part

**listener: {**

```
                       paste: {
                            element: 'inputEl',
                            fn: function (event, inputEl) {
                                var text = event.browserEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
                                if (text.length > /*MaxLength*/ 80) {
                                    scope.fireEvent('exceedpaste', scope, /*MaxLength*/ 80, text.length);
                                }
                                return;
                             }
                        }
```

**}**

Fixed